# What are the examples of integer acute triangles?

Tags: geometry

By an integer acute triangle is meant an acute plane triangle with each side of integer length. But I am curious about the existence of an integer acute triangle **with each side of different length** and about how to prove the existence.

I am sorry about that the first version of this post is not my intention. Thank you so much for your understanding.

Comment: More info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_triangle

Comment: Related: https://oeis.org/A247588  Number of integer sided acute triangles with largest side n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a triangle with sides of length 1, 3, and 3 is definitely acute.  In general, as long as the side lengths satisfy $a \le b \le c$ (just sort the side lengths), $c < a + b$ (the triangle inequality; without this there's no triangle at all), and $c^2 < a^2 + b^2$ (the pythagorean theorem/law of cosines), you have created an acute triangle.  That it's not terribly hard to find sets of integers that satisfy these inequalities; just pick an $a$ and a $b$ and the list of $c$s will be easy to generate.

If you want three *different* sides, all you have to do is make the triangle big enough.  4-5-6 is the smallest such triangle.

Comment: Sorry. My real intention is to ask the existence of integer acute triangle with each side of difference length. Please see the revision.

Comment: The answer above, with minor modification, deals with the change. Replace $a\le b\le c$ by $a\lt b\lt c$. For instance, use $4,5,6$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Much appreciated.

Comment: http://codepad.org/IrPJUH42 This short python script will generate integer scalene (all three sides different) acute triangles.